# How to use Xdebug in Visual Studio Code to debug PHP Scripts in Ubuntu for Xampp

Tags: php, xampp, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I am trying to debug my PHP script using Visual studio code, Xdebug and XAMPP.
Things I did so far:

1. Downloaded latest XAMPP version with PHP 7.2.6
2. Followed all the steps using Xdebug Wizard: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php
3. Added Xdebug extension in Chrome.
4. Added following lines in php.ini:

   ```
   zend_extension = /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/xdebug.so

   [XDebug]
   xdebug.remote_enable = 1
   xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
   ```
5. Added following setting in VS Code:

   ```
   {
   "window.zoomLevel": 0,
   "window.openFilesInNewWindow": "off",
   "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
   "window.restoreFullscreen": true,
   "editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
   "editor.mouseWheelZoom": true,

   "php.validate.enable": true,
   "php.validate.executablePath": "opt\\lampp\\bin\\php-7.2.6",
   "php.validate.run": "onType",
   }
   ```

=> error in VS Code:

> Cannot validate since `opt\lampp\bin\php-7.2`. is not a valid php executable. Use the setting 'php.validate.executablePath' to configure the PHP executable.

Please tell how to resolve this error or any other way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try an older version of Xampp, for instance [7.0.2-1](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Linux/7.0.2/), and then follow the instructions provided by https://xdebug.org/wizard.php and in particular remember to use `phpize` and `php-config` provided with your Xampp installation:

- `/opt/lampp/bin/phpize` instead of `phpize`
- `./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config` instead of `./configure`

Then, in VS Code, install PHP Debug and follow its instructions (your step 4).

Other configurations are not necessary.